# Flutter facebook auth asks for login every time

Tags: firebase, facebook, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am trying to create Facebook login using flutter. It gets logged in but every time I start my app it opens a web page and asks me to 'continue as...' and then goes to the home page.

What I want is for the app to directly go to the home page the next time I log in via Facebook and not go to login again.

I have used 2 dependencies

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

&

```
firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are trying to determine if the user is logged in by checking if the user is loggin on the facebook end.

If you are using Firebase Auth, you have to determine if the user is logged in or not on the firebase end. 
eg:

```
final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
if(user == null) {
   // user is not logged in
} else {
   // user is logged in
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

Android and iOS aren't yet supported for re-auth